# Using R, Unable to Read Image files on Azure DataLakeStore

Tags: r, azure, azure-data-lake, webhdfs, microsoft-r

Using R, I am trying to read image files using WebHDFS API on Azure DataLakeStore. It is not working.

However, I can read the text files  using WebHDFS API sitting next to image file, using same code, with no issues. Also, I can read image files which is openly available on internet.

**1. Code to read JPG on DataLakeStore (doesn't work) using WebHDFS API**

```
a <- GET("https://<mydatalakestore>.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/<folder>/pic.jpg?op=OPEN&read=true",
           add_headers(Authorization = "Bearer <Auth Token>"))
```

> **a$status_code == 403**

OR

```
a <- GET("https://<mydatalakestore>.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/<folder>/pic.jpg",
           add_headers(Authorization = "Bearer <Auth token>"))
```

> a$status_code  == 400

**2. Code to read JPG on Open Web (Works fine)**

```
a <- GET("http://cran.r-project.org/Rlogo.jpg")
```

> a$status_code == 200

```
x <- content(a)
plot(0:1, 0:1, type = "n")
rasterImage(x, 0, 0, 1, 1)
```

**3. Code to read Text (sitting next to image file on DataLakeStore; works fine) using WebHDFS API**

```
a <- GET("https://<mydatalakestore>.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/<myfolder>/testfile3.txt?op=OPEN&read=true",
                   add_headers(Authorization = "Bearer <Auth Token>"))
```

> a$status_code == 200

Comment: The 403 response should have a response body associated with it. Could you share that, omitting any sensitive details? 403 indicates that the bearer token you provided in the request doesn't match a user / service principal with sufficient permissions on the filesystem.

You can use the [portal UI](https://portal.azure.com/) to double-check that the user / service principal has identical permissions on the text file and the image file (and parent folders).

Comment: Thanks Matt for your response. I can rename any file in the folder with no issues. What i think is that command "?op=OPEN&read=true" needs to be different for an image file cuz it works for text files with no problem. my permission is granted at root folder.. RD/WR/Execute well before any files were loaded.

Comment: Do you have any error details besides the response code that you could share? The "?op=OPEN&read=true" shouldn't have to be different for different file types... and when you use the portal UI to download the file, the "?op=OPEN&read=true" is used, too...